# how to extract the size of the uncompressed file from xz api?

Tags: c++, lzma, xz

The xz api allows for multiple compression schemes, but the default is lzma2.
In order to read directly into memory, I want to read the size, allocate that much memory, and write directly into it rather than reading into a fixed 64k buffer.

LZMA2 starts with 10 bytes of metadata, 2 bytes describing the compression with 8 bytes of length. The stream comes after that. But I would like this solution to work for xz which also supports other compression algorithms. Is there an API call that will give access to the length?

I want this to use the xz API, that is commonly available on Linux and well documented (though not this part).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the uncompressed size of an LZMA2 file (.xz / liblzma)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171775/how-to-get-the-uncompressed-size-of-an-lzma2-file-xz-liblzma)

Comment: @RobertHarvey   I don't think so! On Linux you specifically want to use xz, the lzma library is not the one everyone uses, and xz allows other compression engines. I want this to work portably. It seems really odd that xz does not have documentation on how to get the size. Here is an issue from 2016 on the subject: https://github.com/addaleax/lzma-native/issues/15

Comment: That issue is close with [this code.](https://github.com/addaleax/lzma-native/commit/2ec645a833d2d1cc5052275d2cf37e07a7e768fe)  Seems to me that you could use it to determine the uncompressed sizes, if suitable metadata is available.